# Java. "Enter" as a new line,not submission

Tags: newline, enter

how to input

```
1 2  
4 5 4 2 3  
1 2 1 1 1
```

to cmd?
I don't want "1 2" to be read when I press "Enter" but to go to next line and write "4 5 4 2 3"

Comment: What language are you writing in? Why not just buffer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just doing guesses here, since you really didn't give me much to work with, but did you consider using the escape character () to escape newlines?

Alternatively, just create a loop that keeps reading until you enter an empty line:

```
string line;
do {
    cin >> line;
} while (line.size() > 0);
```

Comment: I have to ask: why did I get a -1? I'm trying to help :-)

Comment: -1 For using unallocated memory. If this was just 'concept code' you should have used `std::string`. :)

Comment: Paul, I'm trying to indicate how the concept works. Do you really think it would be wise to include memory management stuff?

Comment: He's obviously a beginner, so you should be careful about what you're showing him. Just saying, you should have used `std::string`. :)

Comment: I removed the downvote, but there's one more thing you should change: your code will only read until the first space. To get a full line you should use `getline(std::cin, line)`.